# I want to combine my two functions into one?

Tags: haskell

I have two functions:

```
firstfunc :: (RandomGen g) => g -> Int -> Float -> [[Int]]
firstfunc rnd n p = makGrid $ map (\t -> if t <= p then 1 else 0) $ take (n*n) (randoms rnd)
  where makGrid rnd = unfoldr nextRow (rnd, n)
        nextRow (_, 0) = Nothing
        nextRow (es, i) = let (rnd, rest) = splitAt n es in Just (rnd, (rest, i-1))

sndfunc firstfunc = head $ do
  lst <- firstfunc
  return $ map (\x -> if (x == 0) then 2 else x) lst

let newFunc = ((firstfunc .) .) . sndfunc

main = do
  gen <- getStdGen
  let g = (firstfunc gen 5 0.3)
  print g
  let h = sndfunc g
  print h
  print $ newFunc gen 5 0.3
```

The firstfunc takes two values like `5` and `0.3` and returns a list of lists like: `[[0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1]]`

The sndfunc takes the head of the above list of lists, which is `[1,0,0,1,0]` from the above example, and replaces the zeroes with 2s like this: `[1,2,2,1,2]`.

Is there a way to combine the two functions such that the firstfunc only returns something like: `[[1,2,2,1,2],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1]]`?

ERROR:

getting parse error parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) on this line: `let newFunc = ((firstfunc .) .) . sndfunc`

2nd EDIT:

```
prac.hs:15:32:
    Couldn't match type ‘[b]’ with ‘a -> a1 -> b0’
    Expected type: [[b]] -> a -> a1 -> b0
      Actual type: [[b]] -> [b]
    Relevant bindings include
      newFunc :: [[b]] -> a -> a1 -> Int -> Float -> [[Int]]
        (bound at prac.hs:15:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘sndfunc’
    In the expression: (((firstfunc .) .) . sndfunc)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: just change if `t <= p then 1 else 0` to `if t <= p then 1 else 2`

Comment: @karakfa : But that will fill 2 in the entire list of lists, and not just in the head.

Comment: you only get head, the rest of the list is not used.

Comment: @karakfa I don't understand. This is the output that I get by trying what you told: [[2,2,2,1,2],[1,2,2,1,2],[2,2,1,1,2],[2,2,2,2,2],[1,2,2,2,1]]. I need this: [[1,2,2,1,2],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1]]

Comment: `sndfunc firstfunc = head ...`  So, after combining two functions you only get the head (first element), the rest is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, I'm talking about the output of the firstfunc, I want its output to be as mentioned. sndfunc only gives me head.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

```
print $ sndfunc $ firstfunc gen 5 0.3
```

or you can define a new function

```
let newFunc = ((sndfunc .) .) . firstfunc
```

and use that.

```
print $ newFunc gen 5 0.3
```

(the extra (.) operators are needed because firstfunc takes three inputs).

Comment: I can't seem to do like this (I mean define a function like this one) inside a text editor. It gives me type error.

Comment: What is the error?  Also, note, the `let` should only be used if in a do block.  And, also note again, that you don't have to put the new function in a variable, `(((sndfunc .) .) . firstFunc) gen 5 0.3` will work as is.

Comment: I edited the code in my question. Is that what you are telling?

Comment: The error you are showing probably is an indention error....  Make sure that the line has the same whitespace in the do block as the line above it.

Comment: Which do block? Please have a look at the code above.

Comment: Since you are not in a do block, remove the `let` (as I mentioned 4 comments up).  It should then work.

Comment: Nah, it gives a type error. Like I mentioned before. I edited my question and added the error.

Comment: You have typed it in backwards....  I wrote `((sndfunc .) .) . firstfunc` in my answer, you typed `((firstfunc .) .) . sndfunc`.  Fix it and it should work.

Comment: It just returns me the head. That is not what I want.